# Outlook VBA find last Row in Excel Worksheet

Tags: vba, excel, outlook

I'm writing a function in Outlook VBA that involves reading content from an excel workbook.

The part I'm struggling with is finding the last row in a column (column A in this example). While the 1st line in the highlighted block correctly displays the content of A1 cell in given worksheet, the second line gives a Error "424" - object required.

Any suggestions into the problem would be greatly appreciated.

```
Public Function openExcel()



    Dim xlApp As Object
    Dim sourceWorkBook
    Dim sourceWorkSheet


    Dim cellVal As String
    Dim lastRow As Long


    Set xlApp = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

    With xlApp
        .Visible = True
        .EnableEvents = True
    End With

    Set sourceWorkBook = xlApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\SAMPLEPATH\Template.xlsx")
    Set sourceWorkSheet = sourceWorkBook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    sourceWorkBook.Activate


    With Activesheet
```

> ```
>         cellVal = sourceWorkSheet.Cells(1, 1)
>         lastRow = sourceWorkSheet.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
> ```

```
    End With



    sourceWorkBook.Save
    sourceWorkBook.Close
    xlApp.Quit



End Function
```

Comment: `End(xlApp)` - don't you mean `End(xlUp)`?  (or maybe `End(xlApp.xlUp)`?)

Comment: I meant `End(xlUp)`, Good Call. However, neither `End(xlUp)` or `End(xlApp.xlUp)` works. The prior results in "error 424 - Object Required" and the latter results in "error 438 - Object doesn't support this property or method"

Comment: Do you have a reference to the Microsoft Excel library?  If not, you will have to define the constant yourself then - i.e. `End(-4162)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to have the ability to use Excel constants within your code, you will need to either

a) Include a reference to a Microsoft Excel Object Library, or

b) Create your own constant, e.g.

```
End(-4162)
```

or

```
Const xlUp As Long = -4162
...
... End(xlUp)
```